# Implementing A Nested State Machine using SMACH library

Tags: ros, smach

I am trying to implement a Finite State Machine using the SMACH library. My state machine has 3 nested state machines and I don't know where am I making a mistake. Any help is highly appreciated.

'''

## State 0 - start

class state0(smach.State):

```
def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
                         outcomes = ['start'])
    
def execute(self, userdata):
    rospy.loginfo('Running State 0')
    return 'start'
```

## State 1 - Home/Stow Position

class state1(smach.State):

```
def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
                        outcomes = ['s2','s3'],
                        input_keys = ['state_1_input'])
    
def execute(self, userdata):
    print(userdata.state_1_input)
    rospy.loginfo('Running State 1')

    if userdata.state_1_input == 1:
        m_1()
        return 's2'
    elif userdata.state_1_input == 2:
        return 's3'
    elif userdata.state_1_input == 3:
        return 's2'
```

class state2(smach.State):

```
def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
                         outcomes = ['sb','s3'],
                         input_keys = ['state_2_input'])

def execute(self, userdata):
    print(userdata.state_2_input)
    rospy.loginfo('Running State 2')

    if userdata.state_2_input == 1:
        m_2()
        return 'sb'
    elif userdata.state_2_input == 3:
        m_5()
        m_6()
        m_7()
        m_8()
        return 's3'
```

class state3(smach.State):

```
def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
                         outcomes = ['sc','s4'],
                         input_keys = ['state_3_input'])

def execute(self, userdata):
    print(userdata.state_3_input)
    rospy.loginfo('Running State 3')

    if userdata.state_3_input == 2:
        m_3()
        m_5()
        m_4()
        m_5()
        m_3()
        return 'sc'
    elif userdata.state_3_input == 3:
        m_3()
        return 's4'
```

class state4(smach.State):

```
def __init__(self):
    smach.State.__init__(self,
                         outcomes = ['stop'],
                         input_keys = ['state_4_input'])

def execute(self, userdata):
    print(userdata.state_4_input)
    rospy.loginfo('Running State 4')

    if userdata.state_4_input == 3:
        return 'stop'
```

def main():
rospy.init_node('nimo_state_machine')

```
Start_state = smach.StateMachine(outcomes = ['end'])    # Outcome of Main State Machine

with Start_state:

    smach.StateMachine.add('State_0',state0(),
                           transitions = {'start':'State_A'})  # Go to State Machine A
    
    state_a_sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes = ['sb_sm'])   # Outcome of State Machine A
    state_a_sm.userdata.flag_a = 1

    with state_a_sm:

        smach.StateMachine.add('State_1',state1(),
                                transitions = {'s2':'State_2',
                                              's3':'State_3'},
                                remapping = {'state_1_input':'flag_a'})
        
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_2',state2(),
                                transitions = {'sb':'sb_sm',
                                              's3':'State_3'},
                                remapping = {'state_2_input':'flag_a'})
        
    smach.StateMachine.add('State_A',state_a_sm,
                            transitions = {'sb_sm':'State_B'})    # State Machine A transitioning to State Machine B
        
    state_b_sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes = ['sc_sm'])   # Outcome of State Machine B
    state_b_sm.userdata.flag_b = 2

    with state_b_sm:

        smach.StateMachine.add('State_1',state1(),
                                transitions = {'s2':'State_2',
                                                's3':'State_3'},
                                remapping = {'state_1_input':'flag_b'})
        
            
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_3',state3(),
                                    transitions = {'sc':'sc_sm',
                                                's4':'State_4'},
                                    remapping = {'state_3_input':'flag_b'})
        
    smach.StateMachine.add('State_B',state_b_sm,
                            transitions = {'sc_sm':'State_C'})    # State Machine B transitioning to State Machine C
    
    
    state_c_sm = smach.StateMachine(outcomes = ['finished'])    # Outcome of State Machine C
    state_c_sm.userdata.flag_c = 3

    with state_c_sm:
        
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_1',state1(),
                                transitions = {'s2':'State_2',
                                                's3':'State_3'},
                                remapping = {'state_1_input':'flag_c'})
        
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_2',state2(),
                                transitions = {'sb':'sb_sm',
                                                's3':'State_3'},
                                remapping = {'state_2_input':'flag_c'})
        
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_3',state3(),
                                transitions = {'sc':'sc_sm',
                                                's4':'State_4'},
                                remapping = {'state_3_input':'flag_c'})
        
        smach.StateMachine.add('State_4',state4(),
                                transitions = {'stop':'finished'},
                                remapping = {'state_4_input':'flag_c'})
        
    smach.StateMachine.add('State_C',state_c_sm,                    
                            transitions = {'finished':'end'})     # State Machine C transitioning to the output of Main State Machine

        
outcome = Start_state.execute()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
main()
'''